# Postgres Server Migration on Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-migrate

I am performing a postgres server migration on azure but I keep getting a failure. Every time I migrate it fails on extensions with the following error:

> Data migration could not be started for one or more of the DBSets. Error details: PGv2RestoreError: PG Restore failed for database 'DATABASE_NAME' with exit code '1' and error message 'error: could not execute query: ERROR: must be owner of extension hypopg'.

Any ideas? The data appears to be in the tables, but the migration in the Azure portal just says failed. This is happening on two servers.

Comment: you can create an extension using `CREATE EXTENSION [ IF NOT EXISTS ] extension_name [ WITH ] [ SCHEMA schema_name ] [ VERSION version ] [ CASCADE ]` and become owner of that extension. First create the extension and then try to restore the database.

Comment: Any update on this? I noticed that `hypopg` was automatically created by `azure_superuser` in system catalogues in a single server. I had to re-create it in `public` to avoid creating it in system catalogues. Now trying to restore the DB to flexible server and facing the same issue...

Comment: Since I didn't need `hypopg`, I ignored it and the restore worked. This was a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: I currently have a support request opened with Microsoft for this. The Azure backend team is currently working on it.